# Server closed connection error when checking if key exists in a redis cluster using stunnel

Tags: linux, redis, stunnel

Using `redis-cli` command line utility with the `-c` switch to connect to a redis cluster with *stunnel* configured and running.

When I execute the `EXISTS` command to verify a key, as expected, it redirects to the node that contains the key however, get the following error:

`127.0.0.1:7000> EXISTS foo
-> Redirected to slot [12182] located at 127.0.0.1:7002
Error: Server closed the connection`

When I don't use *stunnel* it works just fine returning the expected output. However, I want to ensure the connection from the client is encrypted.

Is something needed in the config file *stunnel.conf* such as the nodes' IP addresses and/or ports?  What are recommended steps to configure `redis-cli` connecting to a cluster with stunnel?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure one stunnel connection for each port that your cluster uses.  Then, when your client is redirected to 127.0.0.1:7002, it will be able to connect via the stunnel connection for that port.